# Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 30: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds

Tags: flutter

I have tried all of the solutions available but still not able to connect my emulator and facing this error over and over. Even the option to go to AVD manager stop the emulator is disabled.
I am running windows and have enabled vt-x and disabled hyper v but all to no avail.

Am new to flutter and although the option to run on chrome/edge is available I want it to run on my emulator. Even tried Genymotion but it gave me the error that cant create AVD. Even have intel haxm installed.

Comment: can you include the errors you are getting, also is there is any trouble on running `flutter doctor`?

Comment: I think before, I had to go into my BIOS and enable `virtualization` in order for emulators to work

Comment: The only error is - Failed to launch Pixel 2 API 30: Error: Emulator didn't connect within 60 seconds. After running flutter doctor, although I have installed android studio, its showing that pls install android studio. But while running 'flutter emulators' its showing the emulator I created through Android Studio itself @YeasinSheikh

Comment: I have virtualization enabled @fravolt

Comment: Does other's emulators run without any errors? How about clearing data or creating a new emulator device?

Comment: Can u suggest some emulators? @YeasinSheikh

Comment: i mean can you create others emulator device and those able to run like `Pixel_2_Edited_API_28` and yes you can use others emulators too

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve it by using this link - https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2773

And this one helped me with this problem - https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/2773#issuecomment-782817224

And actually if you're using VS code, don't forget to check you're devices tab and choose emulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in visual studio code when I pressed F5 to run in the emulator.

1. I closed the emulator and then in the vs studio code console `ctrl + p`
2. I wrote the command `Flutter: Select device`
3. There appeared my emulator as offline device.
4. I selected cold boot.

Then it took some more to lunch than usual but everything was working again.